# Trying to resize images for MatchTemplate and getting: error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm learning python by building a bot.

My code;

- Grabs all the images from a specified directory and draws rectangles around any it finds in a real-time display.
- The display is created with `ImageGrab` in a `While` loop.
- then uses `OpenCV` and `MatchTemplate` to actually perform the object detection.

This all works.

I'm trying to speed up my by reducing the size & grayscaling both the images being used for detection and the `ImageGrab` I'm using for my template to match against.

This is my code so far:

```
image_list = []
# Get list of all files in current directory
directory = glob.glob(r"C:\*.png")
# Add images to array
for img in directory:
    ship_img = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2)
    image_list.append(ship_img)

# debug the loop rate
loop_time = time()
# Video Loop
while True:
    # Grab PSS Window and find size 
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Window')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    # Actual Video Loop, cropped down to the specific window,
    # resized to 1/2 size, and converted to BGR for OpenCV
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    (width, height) = (haystack_img.width // 2, haystack_img.height // 2)
    haystack_img_resized = haystack_img.resize((width, height))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img_resized)
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # debug the loop rate
    print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
    loop_time = time()
    
    # Object Detection
    for ships in image_list:
        needle_img = ships  
        result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

        # Get the best match position
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
        
        # Define top left and bottom right
        (H, W) = ships.shape[:2] 
        top_left = max_loc
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + W, top_left[1] + H)
        
        # Highlight Detection
        threshold = 0.9
        if max_val >= threshold:
            cv.rectangle(haystack, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
      
    cv.imshow("Screen", haystack)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I've managed to capture, crop and reduce my template window by 50% with this code section;

```
   # Grab Window and find size 
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Window')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    # Actual Video Loop, cropped down to the specific window,
    # resized to 1/2 size, and converted to BGR for OpenCV
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    (width, height) = (haystack_img.width // 2, haystack_img.height // 2)
    haystack_img_resized = haystack_img.resize((width, height))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img_resized)
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

But when I try and change

`haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` to `haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

and

`ship_img = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2)` to `ship_img = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2)`

I get the error;

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1163: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
```

My `dtypes` are both the same and I haven't changed the shape of my array so I'm not sure why this would be causing an issue with matching.

The documentation says `IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2` downscales an image by 1/2 and I'm resizing my template by 1/2. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The cv.rectangle x,y coordinates need to be integers. You are getting floats from matchTemplate. So convert them to integers before using in rectangle.

Comment: @fmw42 On the full-scale version I'm not getting any issues with drawing rectangles. I'm running into my issue with matchTemplate not rectangle.

Comment: What are the dtypes that you get? MatchTemplate say " It must be 8-bit or 32-bit floating-point."

Comment: Both dtypes are `uint8` @fmw42

Comment: And the shapes?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but bingo I think. `needle_img` is showing as 2 channels, while `haystack` as three. I've some reading to do, thank you. Please post an answer and I'll flag it.

Comment: I believe `cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` should be `cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE is use when reading in a file, but not for changing color spaces

Comment: Tried it, the `shape` has remained the same, `needle_img` is `(16, 32)` and `haystack` is still `(528, 968, 3)`

Comment: I've done some testing and it looks like it's when I resize `haystack` it goes from `(1080, 1920)` to `(528, 968, 3)`. `haystack_img_np` is the first variable that has a shape. I think when I'm resizing it I'm changing it's shape somehow.

Comment: try adding fx=0 and fy=0 in cv.resize() in addition to what you have now. Or change `haystack_img_resized = haystack_img.resize((width, height))` to  `haystack_img_resized = cv.resize(haystack_img, (width, height))`

Comment: New error! That's progress! `TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'`

Comment: what are the shape and dtype of haystack_img.

Comment: what version of Python and OpenCV

Comment: Is haystack_img a normal bumpy array?